# Kakoune module never loaded

Tags: module, nix, kakoune

As I was adding modules to my Kakoune modal code editor such as `kakship`, `kak-rainbow`, `kks` or `alacritty.kak`, I realized that these were never actually loaded by and therefore I never had access to the functions (commands ?) defined by these modules. Typically, `require-module some-module` doesn't work.

Since I use the Nix manager package, I started by checking that my derivations were correct and contained the necessary information. Unfortunately, that's not where the problem lies. However, here's the derivation I'm going to use next, the one concerning `alacritty` terminal support for Kakoune :

```hs
kak-alacritty = pkgs.kakouneUtils.buildKakounePluginFrom2Nix rec {
    pname = "alacritty.kak";
    version = "30909bd";
    src = pkgs.fetchFromGitHub {
      owner = "Superty";
      repo = "alacritty.kak";
      rev = "30909bd89fa3804b31eb3cc91057e38af595a846";
      sha256 = "sha256-M3GN+0mhMIl7mgkqJ0j8TzyfI7ILFjdDUf+65uX094E=";
    };
  };
```

Then I wanted to check that the symlink had been done correctly, so I went to my nix store to check that my modules were present as I wanted them to be. I found that the alacritty module was indeed present, and that its content was also as it should be :

```bash
$ ls /nix/store/lz67ibn7cackz3fn38fax031xsf3s7cq-kakoune-2022.10.31/share/kak/autoload/plugins
alacritty.kak  fzf-kak  kak-rainbow  kakship  kks
    ^
    |
   here
```

The last thing I went to study was the `*debug*` buffer, which contains the following content:

```
*** This is the debug buffer, where debug info will be written ***
shell stderr: <<<
sh: line 1: kks: command not found
/nix/store/gg9mz79r2pq3gpfpmrc93ac5vfyqwc0x-kakoune-2022.10.31/share/kak/autoload/kakrc.kak:41:1: 'require-module': no such module: 'alacritty'
Autoload: could not load /nix/store/gg9mz79r2pq3gpfpmrc93ac5vfyqwc0x-kakoune-2022.10.31/share/kak/autoload/kakrc.kak
error running hook ModuleLoaded(x11)/: 2:5: 'alias': no such command: 'alacritty-terminal'
```

, which I used as a starting point for my previous research.